# init UIView with arguments?

Tags: swift

My `UIView` looks like this :

```
  override init (frame : CGRect)
    {

        super.init(frame : frame)

    }
```

I would like to add an argument such as :

```
 override init (frame : CGRect, number:Int)
```

What is the right way to do it so I can `init` and send arg in *one line* ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would define your class something like this:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    let number: Int

    init(frame: CGRect, number: Int) {
        self.number = number

        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // Need to initialize the number property here. Do so appropriately.
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

The use of the `number` property is just an example. Do what you actually need.

And you would create an instance like this:

```
let mv = MyView(frame: .zero, number: 42)
```

Obviously you would pass a useful frame.

Comment: Doesn’t this throws the error that number is not initialized at aDecoder init?

Comment: @J.Doe After cleaning up some other stuff I had in the playground, I do get an error so I updated my answer to reflect the need to initialize "number" in the `init?(coder:)` method.

Comment: Property not initialized at super.init call in `required init?(coder:)` this not works ;(

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
class CustomView: UIView{

var number: Int

init(frame : CGRect, number: Int) {

    self.number = number
    print("Number = \(number)")
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

   }

}
```

Then add it to the stack like so:

```
  let viewToAdd = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 72, width: 100 , height: 100), number: 1)
  viewToAdd.backgroundColor = .red
  self.view.addSubview(viewToAdd)
```

Comment: It throws: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented